# How does the category name gets mapped to category id in nopcommerce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, nopcommerce

In nopcommerce, how does a category name in a url gets mapped to its corresponding Id.
To clarify: 
How does "apparel" in  http://demo.nopcommerce.com/apparel 
gets mapped to `cagetoryId` in code below

```
public ActionResult Category(int categoryId, CatalogPagingFilteringModel command)
```

I tried to find it in RouteProvider class but couldn't find the exact line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please find this code in the below file

```
Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\Seo\GenericPathRoute.cs
```

Code here: `public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)`

Line number 165.